# Dialog Iframe in liferay is not getting closed after resizing dialog in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

Below is code used for opening dialog iframe

```
Liferay.Util.openWindow({
        dialog:{
                width:'70%',
                modal:true,
                constrain:true,
                destroyOnClose:true,
                cache:false
                },
                uri:'http://localhost:8080',
                id:'id123',
                title:'LocalHost'
                });
```

Once dialog iframe gets open, resize the dialog window and perform any action(click on any links, submit the form) that refresh the dialog window.

After that if you click on close button(cross icon) on dialog's top-right section, dialog is not getting closed instead dialog iframe shows blank screen.

In javascript console it gives `Permission denied`.

Has anyone faced such issue or know how to resolve this, please share?

Comment: This might help you https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-27833

Comment: This issue got resolved by liferay patch provided by Liferay.